Failure to install python-javabridge: How does pip work differently between Python 3.10 and 3.11?
I am trying to install python-javabridge (GitHub link) in order to set up a Java virtual machine to house libraries for different file formats that Python can subsequently refer to. However, the authors of the package have discontinued work on the project, and it doesn't appear to be supported for Python >3.10. However, given how invaluable that library is, I would like to see if I can fix python-javabridge to be installed on newer versions of Python.
Currently, I am testing the installation on Python 3.10 and 3.11 to see how they differ.
Starting with Python 3.10, I tried the following:
> mamba create -n javabridge-test python==3.10.14
> conda activate javabridge-test  # Switch to the environment I want to install it in
> pip install python-javabridge

> # Installation proceeds without issue

However, when I try doing the same thing, but with Python 3.11.8 (having done pip install numpy beforehand to get the dependency ready), I get the following error messages:
Collecting python-javabridge
  Using cached python-javabridge-4.0.3.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.1 in /path/to/envs/javabridge-install/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from python-javabridge) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-javabridge
  Building wheel for python-javabridge (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      /path/to/envs/javabridge-install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge
      copying javabridge/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge
      copying javabridge/jutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge
      copying javabridge/locate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge
      copying javabridge/noseplugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge
      copying javabridge/wrappers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/tests
      copying javabridge/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/tests
      copying javabridge/tests/test_cpython.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/tests
      copying javabridge/tests/test_javabridge.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/tests
      copying javabridge/tests/test_jutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/tests
      copying javabridge/tests/test_wrappers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/tests
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/jars
      copying javabridge/jars/cpython.jar -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/jars
      copying javabridge/jars/rhino-1.7R4.jar -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/jars
      copying javabridge/jars/runnablequeue.jar -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/jars
      copying javabridge/jars/test.jar -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/javabridge/jars
      running build_ext
      javac -source 8 -target 8 /tmp/pip-install-gv_sm6fr/python-javabridge_ea4288a3fc0b4e16815944ed67e58092/java/org/cellprofiler/runnablequeue/RunnableQueue.java
      javac -source 8 -target 8 /tmp/pip-install-gv_sm6fr/python-javabridge_ea4288a3fc0b4e16815944ed67e58092/java/org/cellprofiler/javabridge/test/RealRect.java
      javac -source 8 -target 8 /tmp/pip-install-gv_sm6fr/python-javabridge_ea4288a3fc0b4e16815944ed67e58092/java/org/cellprofiler/javabridge/CPython.java /tmp/pip-install-gv_sm6fr/python-javabridge_ea4288a3fc0b4e16815944ed67e58092/java/org/cellprofiler/javabridge/CPythonInvocationHandler.java
      Note: /tmp/pip-install-gv_sm6fr/python-javabridge_ea4288a3fc0b4e16815944ed67e58092/java/org/cellprofiler/javabridge/CPythonInvocationHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
      Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
      building 'javabridge._javabridge' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      gcc -pthread -B /path/to/envs/javabridge-install/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /path/to/envs/javabridge-install/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /path/to/envs/javabridge-install/include -fPIC -I/path/to/envs/javabridge-install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-2.el8.x86_64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-2.el8.x86_64/include/linux -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-2.el8.x86_64/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-2.el8.x86_64/default-java/include/linux -I/path/to/envs/javabridge-install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/path/to/envs/javabridge-install/include/python3.11 -c _javabridge.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/_javabridge.o
      _javabridge.c:196:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory
         #include "longintrepr.h"
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-javabridge
  Running setup.py clean for python-javabridge
Failed to build python-javabridge
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-javabridge, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Could you advise me on how Python installations via pip and/or setuptools have changed between 3.10 and 3.11, and how this error might be fixed to make python-javabridge's installation compatible with Python 3.11 and newer?

https://github.com/CellProfiler/python-javabridge/issues/22 Reported in 2023, still open. https://github.com/CellProfiler/python-javabridge/commits/master/ Last commit was in 2021. The project seems to be abandoned and not compatible with the latest Pythons.

Yeah, I've seen that issue about it not being compatible with newer Python versions. That's why I'm curious about how it could be tinkered with to be made compatible with the newer Python versions. The Java library is quite invaluable, as there is no pure Python replacement for it yet. Rewriting the package to use something other than javabridge is one option, but I thought that trying to modify javabridge might be a quicker way to go about it. What are your thoughts on this?

1st thing to try: upgrade Cython to the very latest and try to recompile *.pyx and the entire package. If that doesn't help — downgrade Python. If you use old libraries — use older Python.

The difference is that longintrepr.h is no longer included as part of the visible build library in 3.11.
You can copy in longintrepr.h from 3.10, or upgrade all your dependencies with versions that are compatible with 3.11
As shown in your post, longintrepr.h is referenced at line 196 in _javabridge.c
 _javabridge.c:196:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: ....

   #include "longintrepr.h"

It's not surprising if you find that there is current source code for _javabridge.c, that doesn't include that dependency: it didn't work with 3.11 and has been fixed.
Your existing 3.10 compatible build files don't know that they aren't compatible with 3.11, because 3.11 didn't exist when they were created.  Unfortunately, this is a general problem with python dependencies, not just when you are trying to build c extensions with gcc.

Thanks for the reply! Could you clarify what part of the process is responsible for calling longintrepr.h? I have tried parsing through the code on GitHub, but can't find the phrase longintrepr.h anywhere. You also mentioned upgrading the dependencies, but after looking through the requirements.txt and setup.py files, I do not see any maximum version restrictions for the dependencies required. Thanks in advance for your patience in addressing these questions!
